# Entity Framework Foreign Key Column Nulled on Delete

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, entity-framework

Here is my model that EF uses:

```
<Table("Software")>
Public Class Software
    <Key()>
    Public Property SoftwareID As Long
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property ...
    Public Property ...
    Public Property ...
    Public Property ...
    <ForeignKey("Name")>
    Public Overridable Property WhiteList As WhiteList
    <ForeignKey("Name")>
    Public Overridable Property BlackList As BlackList
End Class
```

In my application I want to unlist a software application i.e remove it from the whitelist and blacklist tables (if a record exists).

Here is my code that does that work.

```
        Dim uow As Interfaces.IUnitOfWork = GetUnitOfWork()

        Dim software As Models.Software = uow.Software.GetByID(unlistSoftwareMessage.SoftwareId)

        If software.WhiteList IsNot Nothing Then
            uow.SoftwareWhiteList.Delete(software.WhiteList)
        ElseIf software.BlackList IsNot Nothing Then
            uow.SoftwareBlackList.Delete(software.BlackList)
        End If

        uow.Software.Update(software)
        uow.CommitChanges()
```

When the unit of work is commited, not only are the whitelist / blacklist records deleted (if they existed). But the name value in the software table is deleted (nulled).

The foreign key of the table is by name; not by choice, I have to work with that.

***The question is, how can I delete those records yet maintain the name of the software (which is the foreign key). Preferably without making a second database call.***

.

[image]

Comment: I know it's a trivial bypass of the problem, but what do you say about saving the software name in some temp variable and after the deletion update the name back from that variable?

Comment: Yup, this works and I've already considered this as solution; but I'm trying to avoid make an extra database call.

I've looked turning of cascading deletes and that does not appear to work. I'm no SQL expert, could this be built into MYSQL?

Comment: I suspect that something is wrong inside your unit of work... I would have checked it further instead of you.

Comment: Instead of you, I would have done an experiment and replace the software name field to be different. Something like `_Name`, and see if this affects the deletion. This way you would be sure this is the reason (the name of the field).